# Re: The $T$-matrix, Feynman amplitudes, and getting the scattering corrections from the interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, time-reversal-symmetry, s-matrix-theory

I'm running in circles about something in Scattering Theory at the moment.   Let me summarize.

In quantum theories we are interested in finding experimentally measurable quantities such as scattering cross section.  Stated simply (as I can) the object of interest (computationally) is the S-matrix.  We have this unitary object a series of terms which sum up to a time-ordered exponential.

$S\propto \mathcal{T}\left(e^{i\int dt H_I}\right)$

Now we can assume $S$ can be written term by term and lable the terms past "1" something else called the $T$-matrix.  So that

$S\rightarrow 1+i{T}$ and note that the components of $T$ correspond with the Feynman Amplitude $M$

Supposing that experimentally we are interested in our cross section, we can find this from $|S|^2$, I believe.  The cross section is supposed to be proportional to $\mathcal{M}^2$.

Naively

$|S|^2\rightarrow 1+|T|^2$.  Great. I'm just about ready to conclude that now I can calculate/ predict experimental cross sections from the form of the our $H_i$    But, something is bothering me about this affair.  I think it has to do with the exponential form my of S which appears to be a complex quantity, i.e suggesting that $|S|^2=1$.  I know there must be something I'm botching terribly  with this reasoning, but I can't quite put my finger on it at the moment... Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is your actual question? You say *"something is bothering me"* but you don't really tell us *what*.

Comment: Right.  If S is a complex exponential |S|=1 should be true.  However, that would preclude |T|^2 of having any value.  I've toyed with the idea that out for this is that the components of the scattering matrix are real valued, but I haven't been able to convince myself of this either.  Perhaps if t hat is true someone can.  But if that is not true... I'm out of ideas right now.  The 'what' is my sense of paradox, or hopefully illusion of one.

Comment: Or perhaps working within a specific simple  example would narrow things down.  Suppose$ S=\mathcal{T}e^{-i\int d^4x \phi_I^4}$.  Then the $|S|^2$, without expanding the terms of the exponential is what?  What is the proper method for assessing that question?

Comment: @user41431 If you are trying to say that for infinitesimal time intervals one can write $S = I + iTdt$ to 1st order in $dt$, then what you are hinting at is the unitarity of $S$, $SS^\dagger = S^\dagger S = I$, which implies in turn $T = T^\dagger$. Doing things "naively", by treating operators as "roughly" complex numbers, is definitely not recommended here.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  The point is I don't want to do things roughly.  I'm looking for a general procedure, however.... since it is generally regarded that S  is assessed in the limit as the range of time is from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$  The sources I have so far don't seem to spell that out so far.

Comment: For clarity also I never said anything about" to first order"... it's $S=1+iT$  T is the T matrix it has a bunch of terms.

Answer (score 0):

I recalled a property of S that was evading me at the time,  that S has time reversal symmetry, which ironed some things out.  It appears the object I was looking for would not be |S|^2. Source of paradox= was trying to put a square peg in a round hole perhaps.